# Facebook can not edit test app

Tags: facebook

I am having a problem all of my test apps on Facebook can not be edited and can not be deleted they have warning This page is read-only.

I have also created new test up and it also has This page is read-only. Here is a pictures

[image: This page is read-only]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @rogerdeuce This has noting to do with code it is a problem with the test app on Facebook I have posted it here to see if someone had this problem and was it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. Facebook seems to be working on it.
https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/582921985181374/